# Pandas, isin generates different results for equal elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, in which I am particularly interested in a column `CAPSULE_TEXT`, for which the first 30 rows happen to have the same value:

```py
visit_names['CAPSULE_TEXT'][:30]

0     宅配
1     宅配
2     宅配
3     宅配
4     宅配
5     宅配
6     宅配
7     宅配
8     宅配
9     宅配
10    宅配
11    宅配
12    宅配
13    宅配
14    宅配
15    宅配
16    宅配
17    宅配
18    宅配
19    宅配
20    宅配
21    宅配
22    宅配
23    宅配
24    宅配
25    宅配
26    宅配
27    宅配
28    宅配
29    宅配
```

Moreover, if I convert them to bytearrays and compare bytewise, they are still equal (so there's no extra spaces or any unicode hidden magic).

I have another dataframe, called `coupon_test`, and I want to filter my first dataframe (`visit_names`) to only keep the values that are present in the second. For that I am building the following filter:

```py
visit_names[['CAPSULE_TEXT']].isin(coupon_test[['CAPSULE_TEXT']])
```

Which I then plan to use to filter the `visit_names`. However, the Series it generates have different values for the first 30 elements:

```
0   False
1   False
2   False
3   False
4   False
5   False
6   False
7   False
8   False
9   False
10  False
11  False
12  False
13  False
14  False
15  False
16  False
17  False
18  False
19  False
20  False
21  False
22  False
23  True
24  True
25  True
26  False
27  False
28  True
29  True
```

The value "宅配" is in fact present in the `coupon_test`. My question is why would this behavior occur? Is the order of the series generated by `isin` different from the order of my original dataframe? Or am I using `isin` in a wrong way?

Comment: `visit_names` and `coupon_test` have the same encoding? `visit_names[['CAPSULE_TEXT']].isin(coupon_test[['CAPSULE_TEXT']])` should match the same order as `visit_names`

Comment: Can you try this: `visit_names['CAPSULE_TEXT'].isin(coupon_test['CAPSULE_TEXT'])` so use single `[]` rather than double `[]`

Comment: @EdChum, this works, but in reality I need to filter by two columns, hence the array instead of a string. Do you know why a string works but am array of strings doesn't?

Comment: What you passed was a df consisting of a single column rather than a series or list I don't know why you think this is a string rather than an array of strings?

Comment: I see. So if I do `visit_names[['CAPSULE_TEXT']]` I get a df with a single column, and if I do `visit_names['CAPSULE_TEXT']` I get a series? Or I get df in both cases? Anyway, as I said, when I remove extra brackets, it works, but in my particular case number of columns is more than one, so I what I do in fact is `visit_names[['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME']].isin(coupon_test[['CAPSULE_TEXT', 'GENRE_NAME']])`, in which case I cannot remove the brackets. So I was wondering what is wrong with the extra brackets.